# Need to reboot wireless router to get internet to work after every restart of my laptop

Tags: macos, wireless-networking, osx-lion, wireless-router

I recently got a new ASUS RT-N10 LX wireless router. I set it up using a wired client. After setting up the router (SSID, authentication, etc.), I got rid of the wired client and I was able to connect to the router wireless. Everything worked fine.

**EDIT:** 
But if I restart my wireless client (laptop), I am able to connect to the router wireless but without internet access. I need to reboot the router to get internet to work on the wireless client.
Moreover, I forgot to mention earlier that I am behind a proxy. Does it have anything to do with this problem?

Following is the router's log:

```
Jul 19 11:22:12  klogd started: BusyBox v1.13.4 (2011-07-19 11:18:35 CST)
Jul 19 11:22:12  RTL8192C/RTL8188C driver version 1.4 (2011-03-21)
Jul 19 11:22:16  UPnP: start_UPnP
Jul 19 19:22:19 wlan0: A wireless client is associated - B8:8D:12:07:62:6C
Jul 19 19:22:19 wlan0: WPA-TKIP PSK authentication in progress...
Jul 19 19:22:19 wlan0: A wireless client is associated - B8:8D:12:07:62:6C
Jul 19 19:22:19 wlan0: Open and authenticated
Jan  3 23:23:02 wlan0: A wireless client is associated - B8:8D:12:07:62:6C
Jan  3 23:23:02 wlan0: WPA-TKIP PSK authentication in progress...
Jan  3 23:23:02 wlan0: A wireless client is associated - B8:8D:12:07:62:6C
Jan  3 23:23:02 wlan0: Open and authenticated
Jan  3 23:23:03 wlan0: A wireless client is disassociated - B8:8D:12:07:62:6C
Jan  3 23:33:49 wlan0: A wireless client is associated - 70:F3:95:B4:D2:62
Jan  3 23:33:49 wlan0: WPA-TKIP PSK authentication in progress...
Jan  3 23:33:49 wlan0: A wireless client is associated - 70:F3:95:B4:D2:62
Jan  3 23:33:49 wlan0: Open and authenticated
Jan  3 23:34:04 wlan0: A wireless client is associated - B8:8D:12:07:62:6C
Jan  3 23:34:04 wlan0: WPA-TKIP PSK authentication in progress...
Jan  3 23:34:04 wlan0: A wireless client is associated - B8:8D:12:07:62:6C
Jan  3 23:34:04 wlan0: Open and authenticated
Jan  3 23:40:36 wlan0: A wireless client is disassociated - B8:8D:12:07:62:6C
Jan  4 00:33:54 wlan0: A wireless client is deauthenticated - AC:72:89:4D:FE:31
Jan  4 00:38:23 wlan0: A wireless client is deauthenticated - AC:72:89:4E:0A:34
Jan  4 00:38:59 wlan0: A wireless client is associated - B8:8D:12:07:62:6C
Jan  4 00:38:59 wlan0: WPA-TKIP PSK authentication in progress...
Jan  4 00:38:59 wlan0: A wireless client is associated - B8:8D:12:07:62:6C
Jan  4 00:38:59 wlan0: Open and authenticated
```

**EDIT - 2**: Renewing the DHCP lease, doesn't seem to work for me. My computer doesn't get a new IP on renewal. Infact after DHCP lease renewal, the computer is not even able to connect to the router wireless.

Comment: Which operating system is the client?

Comment: Mac OS X 10.7 (Lion)

Comment: Ah. That changes my answer. I will update it in a bit!

Answer (score 1):

You should not need to restart your router, unless there is a serious firmware issue.

If your router has [DHCP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_Host_Configuration_Protocol) enabled, and your client is set to automatically get addresses via DHCP, running the following should do the same thing as restarting the router:

### Windows:

```
ipconfig /flushdns
```

```
ipconfig /release
```

```
ipconfig /renew
```

## Mac OSX Lion:

*(Thanks @slhck)*

```
sudo killall -HUP mDNSResponder
```

```
sudo ifconfig en1 down
```

```
sudo ifconfig en1 up
```

Or from the GUI:

`System Preferences » Network » Advanced… » TCP/IP`

[image: gui]

Comment: Thanks, it would be great if you could post Mac OS X 10.7 (Lion) equivalents of these. I am trying to google it, but different resources are pointing to different OS X equivalents.

Comment: I do not use Mac OSX, so I am also having difficulty finding the correct answer.

Comment: @stressed_geek See the update.

Comment: @stressed_geek Ping me if you need to know more or if something doesn't work out.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Neither of the approaches you suggested for Mac OSX work for me. After every restart of my computer I have to switch off wireless on my laptop, then restart the router, to get internet to work.

Comment: Renewing the DHCP lease, doesn't seem to work for me. My computer doesn't get a new IP on renewal. Infact after DHCP lease renewal, the computer is not even able to connect to the router wireless.

Answer (score 1):

to get a good image of the situation..

your behind a proxy.. were is the proxy. i.e on wich side of the router?

Is the router talking with the proxy and you with the router
or do you talk to the proxy and the proxy goes to the router?

Does the proxy work with credentials?

Answer (score 0):

The following questions/suggestions might help:

Is this the same for other wireless devices you connect to the router?

Do your wireless clients get a full IP configuration (IP, gateway, DNS, etc) or are there things missing?

Are you capable of pinging a wired host from your wireless host if it doesn't have internet?

It could be a faulty config on your router. Maybe if you reset it to factory defaults and configure it again it might work.

Temporarily shut down the firewall(s) on your router and wireless clients, it could be that your client firewall doesn't trust the wireless network.

Edit: I don't know if your router keeps logs. Try to access it with SSH/telnet or via the webinterface and look for log and post them here.

Comment: Thanks Robert for your suggestions. 

1. This is same for all wireless devices connected to the router.
2. wireless clients are getting full ip configuration.
3. Tried reset to factory settings. Problem still persists.
4. Shutting down the firewall also doesn't help.

Comment: Did you try pinging from a wireless client to a wired one? Also, try a traceroute from a wireless client to google.com and a wired client

Comment: I tried pining google.com and wired client(192.168.1.2) through the wireless client. Both ping and traceroute fail when I don't have internet on the wireless client.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, but I just realized now that the problem is that every time I restart the wireless client, I need to reboot the router to get internet to work on the wireless client. It doesn't matter if a wired client is connected or not.

Comment: I don't know if your router keeps logs. Try to access it with SSH/telnet or via the webinterface and look for log and post them here.

Comment: I have posted logs from the router.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the mac's name to something short with no hyphens in it.  The "wizard" that runs when you turn on a new mac for the first time gives the machine a long name like richards-mac-mini.  Use System Preferences > Sharing to change it to something short like "rsmm" after recording the current name. Doing so worked for me. Note that my wifi router is not an Asus, though.